# Editing a user profile locks my user search reults to that username

Tags: views, search, users

Note, I did not dev this site I am onsite for a couple of days to help with debugging.

Clients site has a View for searching users. After I click Edit the user profile shows, if I save or cancel this edit the search results are locked on that user. Clearing the search field, typing a different user name or refreshing the page doesn't help. The only way to get fresh search results is to click on the Users button again.

Any guidance in this is appreciated. Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks!

Comment: try to run cron , and give a feedback

Comment: Hi sel_space. I have cron running hourly and have run it manually a few times just to test. Still no luck. Thanks though!